# Show that $\lim \inf x_n$ is an adherence value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. Show that $\lim \inf x_n$ is an adherence value of $x_n$.

My proof:

Let's define $a:=\lim \inf x_n$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \geq 1$. We'll show that $|x_{kn} - a| \leq \epsilon$ for $kn \geq N$.

Let's first define our subsequence $(x_{kn})$ as $x_{kn} = \lim \inf \{x_{kn}, x_{kn + 1} \cdots\}$.

Since $x_{kn} \leq a$ it follows that $|x_{kn} - a| = a - x_{kn}$.

But from our definition of $x_{kn}$ it follows that $(x_{kn})$ is a monotonic non decreasing sequence, therefore $x_{kn} \leq x_{kn + 1} \leq \cdots \leq a \rightarrow a -x_{kn} \geq a -x_{kn + 1} \geq \cdots \geq 0$

Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, $(x_{kn})$ is also bounded and therefore $|x_{kn}| \leq L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence we can see that:
$$
-L \leq x_{kn} \leq L \rightarrow a + L \geq a-x_{kn} \geq a - L
$$

Now consider the sequence $s_{kn} = a - x_{kn}$. From what we've previsouly concluded, $s_{kn}$ is monotnic non decreasing, bounded and $s_{kn} \geq 0 $ therefore it'll converge to $0$, and that proves that a is an adherence value of $x_n$.

---

I've seen a simpler proof of this fact using an equivalent statement of adherence value, without the need to show a subsequence... But that's what I initially did without that equivalent statement. Can someone please check my proof?

Should I be more rigorous to show that $s_{kn} \rightarrow 0$?

Thank you. Any critics and comments about my work are highly appreciated.

Comment: You write $x_{kn}$. Is that correct or do you mean to write $x_{k_n}$? Further  your "definition" of $x_{kn}$ ( $x_{kn}=\liminf\{x_{kn}, x_{kn+1}\cdots\}$) is not okay. By a proper definition of $x_{kn}$ it cannot appear in LHS **and** RHS. In a proper definition you can use only things that are defined already. The $x_{kn}$ on RHS is not yet defined, hence cannot be used. I really cannot understand what you are trying to do, so decided to give just a concise proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a:=\liminf x_{n}$ and $y_{n}:=\inf_{k\geq n}x_{k}$ so that
$y_{1}\leq y_{2}\leq\cdots\leq a$ and $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n}$.

If $a$ is *not* an adherence point of sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}$
then some open set $U$ must exist with $a\in U$ and such that $\left\{ n\mid x_{n}\in U\right\} $
is a finite set.

Then some integer $m$ must exist with $x_{n}\notin U$ for every
$n\geq m$ and consequently $y_{n}\notin U$ for every $n\geq m$.

This however contradicts that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n}=a$.

So we conclude that $a$ must be an adherence point of sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for... I wanted to see if you or someone else could check my proof...